# I have got two (.py) files. When the first program comes to end, it will close itself then open and run the second program file. How can ı do it?

Tags: python, file

Here is my first file's codes:

```
from csv import writer


film=[""] #The list contains informations about the film

#İnputs:
filmname=input("Film name: ")
category=input("category: ")
score=input("point: ")
score=str(score)
complement=input("complement: ")
valuablenames=input("İmportant actors: ")

#Appending Inputs
film.append(filmname)
film.append(category)
film.append(score)
film.append(complement)
film.append(valuablenames)

#The Function which appends the list into csv file:
def liste_append(filename,inf_list):
   
    with open("FilmSet.csv", 'a+', newline='') as write_obj: # Open file in append mode
       
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)                       # Create a writer object from csv module
        
        csv_writer.writerow(film)                            # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file

#Calling Function
liste_append("FilmSet.csv",film)

#Jumping to File which converts csv to xlsx
```

***#Jumping to File which converts csv to xlsx***
The part i need your help to close this file and jump to the other one (which is a converter program and named as "converter.py").So when i run this program,it will update the csv file and jump to "converter.py" for updating excel file from csv converted.( deletes the old xlsx and creates new xlsx which is converted from csv )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Best solution

My recommendation would be to turn one of the python files into a package and simply import the required functions.

So in this case put your csv conversion from `conversion.py` into a function like `csv_to_xlsx()` and then `from conversion import csv_to_xlsx()` and then run it at the end of your main file.

### Other solutions

You could use the `subprocess` module with [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) or [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.system). These will allow you to execute python code from another file. Also the worst other solution is `exec()` this allows you to pass python code as a string and execute it. so you could do

```py
exec(open('file.py', 'r').read())
```

Comment: Thanks. This would work to me in this case. But i still wonder is there a way as i asked ? Close the during program and run another one ?

Comment: @ÖmerCan yes, technically you could do ```exec(open('file.py').read())``` what's happening is ```exec()``` takes a string (that's valid python code) and executes it. So in this case the code says: Read this python file and execute the code inside. You could also do something with the ```subprocess``` module or ```os.system```.

Comment: @ÖmerCan I added additional solutions to the answer, would you mind just hitting the checkmark beside to say it's the acceptable answer so people see it first when they view the question :) Thanks, and welcome to stack overflow